# Is there a vim command to select pasted text?

Tags: vim

I find myself often repeating the following pattern of operations.

I usually go into visual mode, select some lines or block. Then I yank them using `y`, and paste them using `p` or `P`. The next step is to select the pasted text, to replace a variable or function name or change indentation.

I know that I can use `gv`to reselect the "origin" but what I would like is a similar command to select the "destination".

`:help gv` mentions :
`After using "p" or "P" in Visual mode the text that was put will be selected.`

but it is only useful when you are replacing a selection by the content of register, not when you are inserting a whole new block.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You are looking for

```
`[v`]
```

[`'[`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#%27%5B) and [`']`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#%27%5D) are marks automatically set by vim to the start and the end of the "previously changed or yanked text". `v` switches to visual mode in between.

Comment: Wow, did not know of these marks, you really are a guru, Luc.

Comment: I have remapped that to `gp` and it works perfectly. This is great because I don't think I would have been able to dig that information from :help ! Thanks! And it is great to change indentation after copying as well.

Comment: :) I've discovered and used `'[` a few years backs in my template-expander plugin. That's not a mark I use every day. It's hard to remember them all.

Comment: Nice, so you could use auto format for insert actions: nnoremap p p`[v`]=

Comment: These marks point at the beginning and end of the file after pasting a block for me.

Comment: It would be great if you can explain how this works.

Comment: There is nothing much to say. `'[` and `']` are marks automatically set by vim to the start and the end of the "previously changed or yanked text". `v` permits to go in visual mode in between.

Comment: I found that this breaks if I have an an autocmd `TextChanged` for autosave. Is there a workaround?

Comment: @jsuth IMO, you should open a new question here (or on vi.SE) where you share your exact autocommand, and may be add a link to this Q/A

Answer (score 14):

I prefer the following simple mapping to Benoit's function

```
nnoremap <expr> g<c-v> '`[' . strpart(getregtype(), 0, 1) . '`]'
```

Learn more about expression maps:

```
:h :map-expression
```

As @ZyX pointed out the strpart is not needed and can be rewritten as:

```
nnoremap <expr> g<c-v> '`[' . getregtype()[0] . '`]'
```

Comment: Yes, I have however some doubts about whether it will work with blockwise selection when the selection is larger than the last line?

Comment: @Benoit Don't doubt, just test. It should work with `set virtualedit+=block`, and note that when pasting blockwise selection vim will fill missing length with spaces, so you will never get situation where `set virtualedit` is required (unless you somehow removed this spaces after pasting without modifying [] marks).

Answer (score 5):

One of your use cases is to change indentation after pasting.

I use the following maps to achieve this:

```
nnoremap <leader>[ `[V`]<
nnoremap <leader>] `[V`]>
```

They do the following:

- de-indent the recently pasted block
- indent the recently pasted block

I find these very useful and well used maps.

Comment: Please don't add the [same answer to multiple questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions). Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates, once you earn enough reputation. If it is not a duplicate, tailor the post to the question and flag for undeletion.