# Can I perform multiple actions on a visual-block selection in Vim?

Tags: vim, text-editor

I'm using GVIM on Windows, if it matters.

I often select a block, do something, and then need to do something else with the same block, but of course once I do anything with the block, I'm out of visual mode.

Is there a way to re-select or act on the previously selected visual block?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I believe `gv` will reselect the previous block...

Comment: I knew it had to be there, and easy. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

<kbd>g</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> as Joe pointed out does the trick (+1), but an extra tip as well is if you do a `:s` with a visual selection, it will automatically populate the marks `'<` and `'>` and those will persist until you make another visual selection.  So, you can do `:'<,'>s/foo/bar/` without having to go back into visual mode and it will still apply to the same range.  Same thing with anything else that uses those marks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have just pasted a visual block, there is also a way to reselect it easily.

See the [following question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4312664/513198) on SO.