# vim: how to select pasted block

Tags: vim

Is there a vim command to directly select a block of text which has just been pasted?

ps. I know about `gv` to reselect a block after exiting visual mode. It doesn't apply to this case.

Comment: Hmm...I wonder if you could add an `autocmd` to run after you paste?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to select it just after paste (before you change anything else), use

```
nnoremap <expr> gV    "`[".getregtype(v:register)[0]."`]"
```

. `[` and `]` marks point to start and end of the last change, v:register is set to the last register used (which is register used for the paste command unless you, for example, yank something), `[0]` selects only first byte of register type (it is required because for blockwise register it returns `<C-v>{width}`) and register type is one byte which is just the same as the keystroke you should use in normal mode to invoke visual mode.

I saw this solution somewhere on SO, you may want to search for it in order to get some alternatives.

Comment: I believe this is the thread you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312664/is-there-a-vim-command-to-select-pasted-text

Comment: `getregtype([{regname}])` If {regname} is not specified, `v:register` is used. So, `getregtype()[0]` also works.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I have this map:

```
:nnoremap gp `[v`]
```

After more research I think the better solution is:
" https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Selecting_your_pasted_text

```
nnoremap <expr> gp '`[' . strpart(getregtype(), 0, 1) . '`]'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had the following maps in my vimrc forever:

```
nnoremap <leader>p `[V`]
nnoremap <leader>[ `[V`]<
nnoremap <leader>] `[V`]>
```

They do the following:

- visually select the recently pasted block
- de-indent the recently pasted block
- indent the recently pasted block

I probably use the indent ones even more than the selection one.