# In vim, how to visual select previously pasted text

Tags: vim

I usually visual select a block and copy/cut it somewhere else, then I found myself always formatting the pasted text, so is there a way to quickly visually select the text again.

Comment: like indenting and stuff. Though this can be acheived via `gg=G`. BTW, did you see this q/a: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312664/is-there-a-vim-command-to-select-pasted-text?rq=1

Comment: You should try `[p` and `]p`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every command that modified the buffer (and yanks) will set the `'[` and `']` marks around the changed area. So you can reformat your pasted block via:

```
`[v`]=
```

Some people go so far as to use the following mapping to reselect last modified chunk of text:

```
nnoremap <expr> gV '`[' . getregtype()[0] . '`]'
```

With this mapping you can just do `gV=` and format your just pasted text.

However if you have the [unimpaired.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) plugin and you are pasting linewise you can use the `=p` command it provides. This will paste and then reformat the text in one go. It also provides some other alternative paste commands `>p` for example will paste one indent level deeper.

Comment: Great answer, master of vim!

Answer (score 1):

For visual mode, `gv` is the standard way to reselect the previous area.

If you want to toggle between start and end positions of the area, just press `o`.

As other answers have mentionned it, you can apply standard `=` command on this reselected area.

It works well after a `p` or `P` paste.

The advantage is that you do not need any custom mapping.

Comment: probably not exactly what I asked

Answer (score 0):

The way I use is  straightforward. The cursor is at the beginning of the pasted text after pasting. The press **V** to switch to visual selection, the press **']** to go the end of the pasted.

They are 3 key presses. If it is too long then you can do mapping for **p**

```
map p pV'[
map P PV'[
```